# How to download a .gz file with Node.js without any third party libraries

Tags: node.js

I simply want to download a .gz file from a URL and save it in a folder. I would like to do this without any third party libraries if possible. Here's what I have so far, but it only downloads an empty file:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')

let file = fs.createWriteStream('./folder/filename.gz')
let request = https.get('https://someurl/somefile.gz', function(res) {
  res.pipe(file)
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a http url using "https" module or is that just a mistake in example?

Comment: @jal Thanks for pointing that out. In reality I AM trying to get the .gz from a https URL... I have fixed my example. :)

Comment: There can be a couple of reasons for that. If you don't get any errors first check if the download works properly in browser, then you should check the status code of the response `res.statusCode`, you might be redirected to another url for actual download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this, using [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) for nodesJS,it looks similar to downloading any other file, just remember to mention the extension of the downloaded file when calling `instead`....Here is an example:

> NOTE: IF you are trying to download from an HTTPS link, use the [HTTPS
>   module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback) instead, its exactly the same, but just replace all the
>   `HTTP` in the following code with `HTTPS`

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

//I added './' assuming that you want to download it where the server 
//file is located, just change it to your desired path, followed by the 
//filename and the EXTENSION
const file = fs.createWriteStream("./result.tar.gz");
const request = http.get("http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/gzip/gzip-1.3.6.tar.gz", (response) => {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```